# Align two children differently in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apache-flex, header

I'd like to have a header with a back button to the left and a text/title in the center of the header.

Like this:

```
<View style={styles.topbar}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.topbarButton}>{" <"}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.topbarText}>Title</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

I'm trying to use flex in `styles.topbar` but nothing of what I tried seems to work.

I am pretty new to flex and React Native so some help with the styles would be great.

Thanks all.

Comment: Please post the styles you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
<View style={{width:devicewidth,flexDirection:'row',height:40,top:0,position:'absolute'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={{left:0,position:'absolute',alignItems:'flex-    start'}}>
      <Text style={styles.topbarButton}>{" <"}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
     <View style={{justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Text style={styles.topbarText}>Title</Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

The above code will print back button at the top left and text at the center. Flex direction is used to indicate view to print in a row direction.